# Correct Way to Parallelize Pandas on Data Frame Slices

Tags: python, pandas, concurrency, vectorization, data-science

let's assume I have a data frame with N multi valued categorical columns and I want to encode them as fast as possible using Pandas.

This is what i achieved so far, not sure if it is the best way to parallelize Pandas though (I would prefer a vectorized approach where possible) :

```
def encode_single_categorical(input_series):
    encoded_categorical_feature_data_frame = input_series.str.join(
        '|').str.get_dummies().astype(
        pd.np.bool).add_prefix(
        input_series.name + '_')
    return encoded_categorical_feature_data_frame


def encode_multi_valued_categorical_features(input_data_frame, categorical_features):
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
        encoded_categorical_data_frames = p.map(encode_single_categorical,
                                                [input_data_frame[categorical_feature] for
                                                 categorical_feature in categorical_features])
    return pd.concat(encoded_categorical_data_frames, axis=1)
```

I added a test in addition, but the focus here is the approach. THe solution functionally works, It's more a question about " is it a best practise in Pandas ?

```
def test_encode_multi_valued_categorical_features(self):
    categorical_features = ['productCategories', 'productTypes']
    input_data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'querySource': ['source1', pd.np.nan, 'source3'],
                                     'productTypes': [["t1", "t2", "t3"], ["t6", "t4", "t3"], ["t6", "t1"]],
                                     'productBrand': ['brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3'],
                                     'productCategories': [["c1", "c2", "c3"], ["c6", "c4", "c3"], ["c6", "c1"]],
                                     })
    expected_data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'querySource': ['source1', pd.np.nan, 'source3'],
                                        'productBrand': ['brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3'],
                                        'productCategories_c1': [True, False, True],
                                        'productCategories_c2': [True, False, False],
                                        'productCategories_c3': [True, True, False],
                                        'productCategories_c4': [False, True, False],
                                        'productCategories_c6': [False, True, True],
                                        'productTypes_t1': [True, False, True],
                                        'productTypes_t2': [True, False, False],
                                        'productTypes_t3': [True, True, False],
                                        'productTypes_t4': [False, True, False],
                                        'productTypes_t6': [False, True, True],
                                        })

    result = utils.encode_multi_valued_categorical_features3(input_data_frame, categorical_features)
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(result, expected_data_frame)
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @RafaelC , I added the simple test I use.
But as I mentioned in the question, the problem here is not functional ( the solution works). It's more about the correctness of the parallel approach, if no better option can be used.

Comment: @AlessandroBenedetti it's a little hard to see what you are trying to achieve, do you have your own mapping you want to apply or any encoding would do? Have you tried LabelEncoder in the sklearn package?

Comment: Hi @Jimmy, the logic itself is working as I mentioned.
You can see it from the test, it takes in input  a list of columns which contains list of  categories and encode them in boolean columns ( one hot encoding).
I was more curious to know if parallelising that way on a column base does make sense in Pandas :)

Comment: Hi @AlessandroBenedetti I see what you are trying to do now - I have made a suggestion in the answer section hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do it with the built-in vectorised methods in Pandas, which reads a lot cleaner and should be faster.

Below is an example for one column, which you should be able to convert into a function and loop over all relevant columns.

```
# get super list of all lists in column 'productCategories'
list_all_cat = input_data_frame['productCategories'].sum()
print(list_all_cat)
> ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c6', 'c4', 'c3', 'c6', 'c1']

# get unique list of productCategories
list_all_cat_unique = list(set(list_all_cat))
print(list_all_cat_unique)
> ['c4', 'c6', 'c2', 'c3', 'c1']

# loop over this unique list
for cat in list_all_cat_unique:
    # new column defaulting to False
    input_data_frame['productCategories_' + cat] = False
    # encode
    input_data_frame.loc[input_data_frame['productCategories'].apply(lambda x: cat in x) , 'productCategories_' + cat] = True
print(input_data_frame['productCategories_c4'])
> 0    False
  1     True
  2    False
  Name: productCategories_c4, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Hey Jimmy, I don't know beforehand the category 'c1' and the column productCategories contains a List of strings ( see example in the test)

Comment: See my updated answer and example output for your test dataframe

Comment: mmm Jimmy, My point is exactly to avoid looping on each relevant column.
The function that generates the encoded columns from a single one (def encode_single_categorical(input_series)) is fine.
I want to run this function in parallel on all the relevant columns.
The result will be a Data Frame.
I am playing with apply ( encoded_categorical_feature_data_frames = input_series_list.apply(func=__encode_multi_valued_categorical_feature, axis=0) per column,).
It works and return the correct list of data frames but raise an error as it's not meant to support a list of data frames in output.